# Como obter latitude e longitude sem internet no Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Como faço para pegar a latitude e longitude em `Java` para o `Android` sem usar a internet, somente com o GPS.
Acho que existe alguma maneira sim, pois o aplicativo "Mapas" do `Android` não usa a internet.
Se alguém souber por favor ajude-me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Olhe isso:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag para o status do GPS
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag para o status da rede
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag para o status do GPS
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // localização
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // A distância mínima, em metros, para mudar as atualizações
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // O tempo mínimo, em milissegundos, entre as atualizações
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declarando um Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // pegando o status do GPS
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // pegando o status da rede
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // nenhum provedor de rede está habilitado
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // Primeira obtenção da localização pelo provedor de rede
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // se GPS habilitado pega lat/long usando os serviços do GPS
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Para de usar o listener do GPS
     * Chamando esse método o GPS vai parar em seu aplicativo
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Método para obter a latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Método para pegar a longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Método para checar se o GPS/Wi-Fi está habilitado
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Método para mostrar as configurações me um AlertDialog
     * Pressionando Configurações o botão vai mostrar Opções de Configuração
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Definindo Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Definindo Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS não está habilitado. Você deseja ir em configurações?");

        // Ao pressionar o botão Configurações
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Ao pressionar o botão cancelar
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Mostrando Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Use dessa forma:

```
gps = new GPSTracker(PromotionActivity.this);

// checa se o GPS está habilitado
if(gps.canGetLocation()){
    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
}else{
// não pôde pegar a localização
// GPS ou a Rede não está habilitada
// Pergunta ao usuário para habilitar GPS/Rede em configurações
    gps.showSettingsAlert();    
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652219/find-latitude-and-longitude-with-out-using-internet-in-my-android-phone

Comment: Explicação sobre o código. O Android provê tanto um `NETWORK_PROVIDER` (rede) quanto um `GPS_PROVIDER` (gps) para o [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). O código em questão verifica e tenta tirar medidas primeiro da rede (se estiver habilitada) e então do GPS (novamente se estiver habilitado).

Comment: +1 pelo comentário, mas resolvi não por isso pois estava comentado no código. Obrigado Anthony!