# Como obter as coordenadas do gps em java no android

Tags: java, android

Qual a melhor forma de obter a latitude e longitude no android.
Ex. após a solicitação (toque no botão) o usuário aguarda o gps obter as coordenadas e após isso exibe-as para o mesmo.

Comment: Você mesmo não obteve uma resposta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13158/4337)?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, existem várias maneiras, vou te passar uma:

Primeiro você cria um service para obter a latitude e longitude, depois é só instanciar ele quando for clicar em algum botão para obter as coordenadas.

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private final Context mContext;

    // flag para GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag para network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag para GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // A distância mínima para mudar Atualizações em metros
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 metros

    // O tempo mínimo entre as atualizações em milissegundos
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0; // 1 minute=1000 * 60 * 1

    // Declarar a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // obter o status GPS
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // obter o status da rede
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                //Nenhum provedor de rede está habilitado
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // Primeiro localização obter de provedor de rede
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    //eric

    /**
     * para de usar GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function para obter latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function para obetr longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Função para verificar GPS / Wi-Fi habilitado
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function para abrir o alerta
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // titulo da mensagem de config
        alertDialog.setTitle("Configurar GPS");

        // mensagem de configuração
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS não Ativado. Você deseja abrir o menu de configuração?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Configuração", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // btn cancelar
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Exibir alerta de mensagem
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        getLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

E depois para obter os dados na sua `MainActivity`, por exemplo (ao clicar em um botão):

```
// clicando no botao
btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {        
        // instancia o service, GPSTracker gps
        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        // verifica ele    
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            // passa sua latitude e longitude para duas variaveis
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            // e mostra no Toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sua localização - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

E lembrando, não esqueça das permissões:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Ok @Alessandro Barreto, tranquilo, mas se o service nao tem as coordenadas "por algum motivo" na hora do clique, como eu as resgato apos o gps obter os dados, na minha activity?

Comment: Tentei usar mais deu location lat e long 0.0

Comment: tentei usar aqui também, mas me foi retornado 0.0 em ambos os casos